# Better Skype taskbar icon?

Tags: skype, windows

One thing I miss from Windows is that I always had a Skype icon at the bottom of my screen that would tell me when I had new messages.  Right now, the Skype icon in the Mac taskbar only lets me click on it to change my online status.  Is there an app out there for a better Skype icon or would there be a way to customize it to do what I want?  On Windows, it turns gold and there's a number with how many new messages you have.

Answer (score 2):

In the Skype Preferences, under the Notification tab, you can set the Skype icon to bounce, play a sound and display a built-in visual notification when you receive new messages. Click on the "Event" dropdown to select the events you require. Is this the sort of thing you were after?

[image]

Comment: No, I hide my dock usually to get more space on the screen (although I don't think it matters) and I would like to just have the icon in the taskbar let me know when there is a new message, for two reasons:
1.  The box that comes up in the corner of my screen is annoying.
2.  Sometimes I leave my computer and don't like to have to check Skype for new messages each time I come back.

Comment: @AndrewLatham OK, so you can disable visual notifications. But even when the dock is hidden, I'm fairly sure you can still see the icon bounce.